# MUI Table shows no data when and shows loading while waiting on data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, progress-bar, react-query

how to show loading or progress while waiting on the data then if there is no data that is fetched it will show a message "No data". I tried conditioning when there if userData === 0 it will show no  data but it the message is still not showing and for the loading I am not sure

[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OLbN.png)

```
          <TableContainer component={Paper} sx={{maxHeight: 400, minHeight: 400}}>
            <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} size="small" aria-label="a dense table">
             
              <TableBody>

                {/* {userData?.data === 0 && (
                  <TableRow hover role="checkbox" >
                    <TableCell colSpan={12} align='center'>
                      <h6>
                        No Data
                      </h6>
                    </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                )} */}

                {userData?.data?.length > 0 &&
                  userData?.data?.map((row) => {
                    return (
                      <TableRow hover role="checkbox" tabIndex={-1} key={row.id}>
                        <TableCell align='center'>{row.id}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{row.id_prefix}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{row.id_no}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{row.first_name}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{row.middle_name}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{row.last_name}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{row.username}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{row.sex}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{row.location_name}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{row.department_name}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{row.company_name}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell sx={{textAlign: "center"}}>
                          <Button
                            id="composition-button"
                            aria-controls={open ? 'composition-menu' : undefined}
                            aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
                            aria-haspopup="true"
                            onClick={(e) => {
                              handleToggle(e)
                              setArchiveData(row)
                              setResetData(row)
                            }}
                          >
                            <MoreVertIcon />
                          </Button>
                          
                        </TableCell>
                      </TableRow>
                    );
                  })
                }

              </TableBody>
            </Table>
          </TableContainer>
```

Comment: instead of `userData?.data === 0` you probably wants `userData?.data.length === 0`